# An indexed/ordered column that easy to generate the value that has been inserted between values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a column with "insertable indexed key", by that, I mean

1. I can insert some random data between value A and the value next to A, like 20 -> (insert data) -> 21
2. I can use the key(probably unique key) to operate on data, like getByKey, deleteByKey, etc.
3. I can compare between keys, like I will know, something between 20 and 30 is greater than 20 and less than 30(**values don`t have to be numeral, comparison don`t have to be numeric comparison**)

#### what I have tried - with primary key auto_increment

apparently I can not use auto_increment pk in this case, I can not insert between id=20 and id=21

#### what I have tried - with varchars

Probably I can use varchars, for example:

```
# column type varchar(10) -  original data
"20"
"21"

# insert 2 item between 20 and 21

"20"
"201"  <- insert first
"202"  <- insert second
"21"

# insert 1 item between 201 and 202

"20"
"201"
"2011" <- insert
"202"
"21"
```

The problem here is that

1. I have to **maintain whole generating algorithm by myself**, which is very complicated. I have to check whether there is a value on the same spot, or do a few comparisons and have to decide whether to expand the digits or not
2. If I manage to solve problem 1, I have to add thread-safe code, which is much more complicated.

#### what I have tried - with multiple column

I don`t think multiple columns are solutions here, I want to keep it simple. But if there are solutions that uses multiple columns, I really want to hear it.

#### question

can you give a solution for this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think that you'd look at tree-oriented patterns which maintains the tree nodes to be ordered. Especially if you did not need to move nodes and subtrees in the tree. For example, see 2-3 or 2-3-4 tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing what every BASIC programmer has dealt with since 1964. :-)

You could use a FLOAT or DOUBLE column as the primary key, so you could keep inserting fractional values between the existing primary key values. There's a limit to the precision, given that these data types are of fixed size, but it's not clear from your question how frequently you would have to insert a new row between values.

```
create table mytable ( id float primary key );

insert into mytable (id) values (20), (21);

insert into mytable (id) values (20.5);

insert into mytable (id) values (20.75);

select * from mytable;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
|    20 |
|  20.5 |
| 20.75 |
|    21 |
+-------+
```

This also would require you to manage the id generation yourself, which you said you find inconvenient.

And as you said, making it thread-safe would require you to lock ranges of rows, so you could prevent race conditions.

I don't think there is any solution to do what you want that works as automatically as an auto-increment integer. You're going to have to implement some code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since you are using numbers like 20.5 20.75, are you suggesting to generate new data of the middle value in a range?

Comment: Any value between the two numbers would suffice. Choosing one midway between the existing PK values is optimal if you expect it's equally likely for future values to be between the new values.